# Gaussian curvature of a holomorphic curve in complex 2-space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $M\subset\mathbb C^2$ be a Riemann surface that is a holomorphic submanifold of complex 2-space. As such it inherits a Riemannian metric from $\mathbb C^2\approx\mathbb R^4$.

Each point of $M$ has a tangent "line" — a real 2-plane — which when translated to the origin of $\mathbb C^2$ becomes a complex line in $\mathbb C^2$, i.e., a point of $\mathbb{CP}^1\approx\mathbf S^2$, the unit 2-sphere.

This defines a mapping $M \to \mathbf S^2$. Now view this as a mapping between real Riemannian surfaces.

Is it true that the Jacobian determinant of this mapping at any $p\in M$ is the Gaussian curvature of $M$ at $p$?

(If not, what is it?)

And are there generalizations to holomorphic curves in $\mathbb C^n$?

Any references to the literature will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a classic paper by Phillip Griffiths, *On Cartan’s method of Lie groups and moving frames as applied to uniqueness and existence questions in differential geometry*, Duke Math. J. **41** (1974), 775–814, that answers your question and quite a bit more.  The formulae you want occur in Section 4 (Holomorphic curves) or can easily be derived from the formulae there.  This paper is available [online](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/cartansmethod.pdf) from the IAS.

Just so you'll have the answer with the correct normalizations:
Give $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$, regarded as the space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^n$, its $\mathrm{U}(n)$-invariant metric $h_{n-1}$, normalized so that a linear $\mathbb{CP}^1\subset\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ has Gauss curvature $+1$. Let $\gamma:M\to \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ be the Gauss map. Then
$$
\gamma^*(h_{n-1}) = -2K\,g_M\,,
$$
where $g_M$ is the metric induced on $M\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ and $K\le 0$ is the Gauss curvature of $g_M$.  In particular, note that the Gauss map $\gamma$ is (weakly) conformal.

*Remark:* Note the factor of $2$, which is not present for the Gauss map of a minimal surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Also, note that some sources prefer to normalize $h_{n-1}$ so that the area of a linear $\mathbb{CP}^1\subset\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ is $\pi$ rather than $4\pi$.  In this case, the factor of $2$ in the formula above gets replaced by a factor of $\tfrac12$.

Comment: Thanks, Robert!  (That is certainly one of the longest titles of any math paper I've seen.)

Comment: @DanielAsimov, I just want to second Robert's description of this paper as being classic. I suppose I'm biased, but I gotta say that this is one of my favorite math papers. And the title does explain exactly what is in it. There is also a paper by Griffiths and Harris that I always think of as being a sequel to this paper. It proves theorems in algebraic geometry using exterior differential systems.

Answer (score 4):

In any dimension, you can take a Darboux frame $A_i$ about $p$ (this is an easy effective computation) and a local coordinate about $p$ say $z$, Then in a neighborhood about the the point, $C$ is given by $p+zA+z^2B+...$. Now the question becomes computing the curvature of a graph of a function.

Comment: Good point, this is a natural way to derive the result. And I can compute the curvature of the graph of a function. But I was surprised at the complexity of the expression for the gaussian curvature of a parametric Riemann surface embedded in ℂ^2 locally via z |—> (f(z), g(z)), where f and g are entire functions, say.